# Java Avro map, union Json representation

Tags: java, json, dictionary, union, avro

I'm trying to generate a JSON file based on Avro schema using Java.

This is the Avro that is parsing generated JSON file:

```
{
   "namespace": "com.abc.schemas",
   "type": "record",
   "name": "Event",
   "fields": [
              {"name": "customer", "type": "string"},
              {"name": "signature", "type": [null, "bytes"], "default": null},
              {"name": "context", "type": [null, {"type": "map", "values": "string"}]}
              ]
 }
```

I read Avro documentation and ask google many times but still, I have no idea how to create data that will be valid for those two types: Union and Map.

```
 private JSONObject objectFiller(JSONObject json) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        json.put("customer", "AnyStringForTest");
        json.put("signature", ???????Avro Union bytes type?????);
        json.put("context", ????????Avro Map type??????);
        ......
```

Does anyone have any ideas?